# Does an official IETF-codified URN exist for PGP keys?

Tags: pgp

I've been able to locate http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/draft-swartz-pgp-urn-00, but it appears to be an unofficial proposal never submitted to the IETF. Does it hold any water?

Answer (score 0):

I quick search on the RFC documents would reveal that there is no such thing.

The URN namespace is registered ([RFC 8141, 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141.html#section-6)), and the IANA [Uniform Resource Names (URN) Namespaces](https://www.iana.org/assignments/urn-namespaces/urn-namespaces.xhtml) does include a *Namespace Identifier* (NID) ([RFC 8141, 2,1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141.html#section-2.1)) `pgp`. On the other hand, there is an IANA registry for [PGP parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/pgp-parameters/pgp-parameters.xhtml), as defined in [RFC 4880, 10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-10).

### The URN namespace has constraints

PGP fingerprints would never meet URN namespace constraints ([RFC 8141, 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141.html#section-5)), as they only have *common definitions*, but they are not *unique* nor *assigned in a consistent way*.

> A URN namespace is a collection of names that obey three
> constraints:    each name is (1) unique, (2) assigned in a consistent
> way, and (3)    assigned according to a common definition.
>
> 1. The "uniqueness" constraint means that a name within the URN
>    namespace is never assigned to more than one resource and never
>    reassigned to a different resource (for the kind of "resource"
>    identified by URNs assigned within the URN namespace).  This
>    holds true even if the name itself is deprecated or becomes
>    obsolete.
> 2. The "consistent assignment" constraint means that a name within
>    the URN namespace is assigned by an organization or created in
>    accordance with a process or algorithm that is always followed.
> 3. The "common definition" constraint means that there are clear
>    definitions for the syntax of names within the URN namespace and
>    for the process of assigning or creating them.

Of course the [RFC 8141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141) did not exist at the time Aaron Swartz wrote his draft ([draft-swartz-pgp-urn-00](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/draft-swartz-pgp-urn-00)), but the *uniqueness of assignment* was in the [RFC 2611](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2611), too.

#### PGP fingerprints are not assigned but hashes

There is no organization assigning the fingerprints, but they are formed by hashing ([RFC 4880, 12.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-12.2)):

> For a V3 key, the eight-octet Key ID consists of the low 64 bits of
> the public modulus of the RSA key.
>
> The fingerprint of a V3 key is formed by hashing the body (but not
> the two-octet length) of the MPIs that form the key material (public
> modulus n, followed by exponent e) with MD5.  Note that both V3 keys
> and MD5 are deprecated.
>
> A V4 fingerprint is the 160-bit SHA-1 hash of the octet 0x99,
> followed by the two-octet packet length, followed by the entire
> Public-Key packet starting with the version field.  The Key ID is the
> low-order 64 bits of the fingerprint.

#### PGP fingerprints are not guaranteed to be unique

The [RFC 4880, 12.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html#section-12.2) also notes that PGP fingerprints are not necessarily unique:

> Note that it is possible for there to be collisions of Key IDs --
> two different keys with the same Key ID.  Note that there is a much
> smaller, but still non-zero, probability that two different keys have
> the same fingerprint.